# "IndexError: list index out of range" error in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I get an error after running my file.
File `"C:Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Research/trainer1file (1).py"`, line 42, in process 
    `iteratorclasses = iter(sorted(os.walk(data))[1])`

`IndexError: list index out of range`

```
def process(data, mode, batch_size):
    images, labels = list(), list()
    if mode == 'file':
        with open(data) as f:
            data = f.read().splitlines()
        for d in data:
            images.append(d.split(' ')[0])
            labels.append(int(d.split(' ')[1]))
    elif mode == 'folder':
        label = 0
        iteratorclasses = iter(sorted(os.walk(data))[1])
        classes = next(iteratorclasses)
        for c in classes:
            c_dir = os.path.join(data, c)
            iteratorwalk = iter(os.walk(c_dir))
            walk = next(iteratorwalk)
            # Add each image to the training set
            for sample in walk[2]:
                # Only keeps jpeg images
                if sample.endswith('.jpg') or sample.endswith('.jpeg') or sample.endswith('.JPG'):
                    images.append(os.path.join(c_dir, sample))
                    labels.append(label)
            label += 1
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown mode.")
    images = tf.convert_to_tensor(images, dtype=tf.string)
    labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.int32)
    image, label = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels],
                                                 shuffle=True)
    x, y = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=batch_size,
                          capacity=batch_size * 8,
                          num_threads=4)
    return x, y
```

Comment: You will never improve if you rely on others to debug your code – show any attempts you have made to track the source of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndexError: list index out of range`

is immediately a warning sign. Just read the error! It says that the `l[i]` where `l` is the list and `i` is the index does not exist since `l` does not have `i` or more indices.

e.g. Let's say I run in Python

```
l = [1,2,3]
l[1]
```

What will it return? `2`, of course.
What about `l[10]`?

There is no 10th index so it'll return `IndexError: list index out of range`.

I'll let you away this time, but you just **can't** give us code and the error and expect us to solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have anything in the directory you are trying to walk through, that's why the index is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted()` in your case, will return a list with **one** element, namely a set that contains root dir, list of directories and list of files. therefore the error (because you want to access index 1, so the **second** element, which is not existing).